# Problem with alias in Sqliteman trying to make unique id´s

Tags: sql, sqlite

I´m trying to translate this function from SQL server to Sqlite, how can i do it? I know it´s different but I just couldn´t. Any information will be awesome. Thanks

This is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    "numId" INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    "prefix" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "id" AS ("prefix"+RIGHT('000000'+CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(7)),7))PERSISTED,
```

Thanks.

Comment: (1) Your syntax is SQL Server syntax, so it is not surprising that it doesn't work in SQLite.  (2) SQLite does not (yet) support generated columns, so you cannot do this in that database.

Comment: And how can I make the same that it´s suposed to do with that code in SQLite? Thanks.

Comment: You can' t have this type of column in SQLite. What you can do is create a query that will return the calculated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal SQL tables are called [rowid tables](https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html), and have a unique integer as their primary key (A [`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) column aliases this rowid). So there's the `IDENTITY` bit taken care of.

While Sqlite 3.31 (In beta as of this writing) supports generated columns, until versions with that feature become widely available over the next few years, you can either create a [`VIEW`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) that adds your custom prefix, or do it in each individual `SELECT` where it matters. Something like:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE actual_user(numId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, prefix TEXT NOT NULL);
sqlite> CREATE VIEW user(numId, prefix, id) AS
   ...> SELECT numId, prefix, printf('%s%07d', prefix, numId) FROM actual_user;
sqlite> INSERT INTO actual_user(prefix) VALUES ('TEST'), ('TEST'), ('TESTX');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM user;
numId       prefix      id
----------  ----------  ------------
1           TEST        TEST0000001
2           TEST        TEST0000002
3           TESTX       TESTX0000003
```

You might also emulate it with triggers for your table that updates the `id` value on insertion and update. This more closely mimics a persist (stored in SQLite lingo) generated column, while the view mimics a virtual column:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE user(numId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, prefix TEXT NOT NULL, id TEXT);
sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER user_ai AFTER INSERT ON user
   ...> BEGIN UPDATE user SET id = printf('%s%07d', new.prefix, new.numId) WHERE numId = new.numId; END;
sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER user_au AFTER UPDATE OF numId, prefix ON user
   ...> BEGIN UPDATE user SET id = printf('%s%07d', new.prefix, new.numId) WHERE numId = new.numId; END;
sqlite> INSERT INTO user(prefix) VALUES ('TEST');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM user;
numId       prefix      id
----------  ----------  ------------
1           TEST        TEST0000001
sqlite> UPDATE user SET prefix='APPLE' WHERE numId = 1;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM user;
numId       prefix      id
----------  ----------  ------------
1           APPLE       APPLE0000001
```